# how to make auto-complete smarter when editing layout xml code in android developing with eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

When I edit layout xml code of android in eclipse,I find the auto complete is not so smart.

For example,I want to write **android:layout_width="wrap_content"**,when I input **android:layout_w** ,the auto complete module will work ,some relevant attribute display waiting for my selection.

when i input enter,this code will become like bellow:

**android:layout_width=""**

The cursor is between the two double-quotes.

As you know ,android:layout_width have three attribute:wrap_content,fill_parent and match_parent .I have to input this attribute manually because the auto-complete is invalid at this time.One way to make auto-complete effective is to delete **=""** after android:layout_width and input **=**.

I think it is not so smart.Any solution about this problem?

Comment: make it as a dynamic. means on runtime you can create dynamic auto-complete control. as par your requirment

Comment: Easiest solution is to use Android Studio instead of Eclipse. It's a lot smarter (and more stable) when it comes to layout editing. If you do decide to stick with Eclipse, I believe pressing ctrl+enter between the double quotes should bring up the list for you.

Comment: @kha ，you solved my problem !however,it is Alt+/ but not ctrl+enter for my eclipse settings that bring up the attribute list.Thanks for all gays that help me!